# Is there a canonical method a host can use to self-rename?

Tags: hostname

Naming `hosts` and keeping track of them is a lot of work on a home network or on a test cluster of VMs.

Is there a canonical way to make a host self-rename from whatever name it was initially set with to something unique such as a string representation of its first `MAC` address, its `IP` or something like it?

Answer (score 0):

Try `autoyast` use an XSLT processor like `xsltproc`.  if you have an AutoYaST control file and want to fill out the host name via script

https://www.suse.com/documentation/sles-12/singlehtml/book_autoyast/book_autoyast.html#CreateProfile.XSLT

Comment: Try how? Can you give an example of the command that would solve the OP's problem? Otherwise, this is a link-only answer.